# Membership.FindUsersByEmail - SQL Wildcards

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

I'm using an ASP .NET Membership database to authenticate users in a web application.

Users log in using their email addresses but something else is used in the Username field of the database.

So on the login form, I fetch my users using [`Membership.FindUsersByEmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2ec0bts.aspx)

The problem is that this function uses a 'LIKE' in SQL and that SQL wildcards are not escaped in that method.

So using the method on, say, a_df@example.com will return the usernames for both a_df@example.com and asdf@example.com (because of the underscore being treated as a wildcard).

According to wiki, quotes, %, and a bunch of other characters are accepted in e-mail addresses.

While I could do something like

```
emailAddr = emailAddr.Replace("_", "[_]").Replace("%", "[%]")...
```

before calling Membership.FindUsersByEmail, i'm thinking that there must be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Why are you using a LIKE statement?  Don't your users know how they entered their own email addresses?  I have never accidentally gone to GMAIL and typed in just 'allen@gmail.com.' (or, more accurately: .[obfuscated]@gmail.co).

Comment: I'm not the one using a like statement. System.Web.Security.Membership.FindUsersByEmail is. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2ec0bts.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a situation like this I think I would enforce that the email address had to be unique and then just get the user via [MembershipProvider.GetUserNameByEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getusernamebyemail.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, unique email addresses are already enforced. I just didn't know about that method.

Comment: I just looked down the intellisense and stopped when I found FindUsersByEmail. GetUserNameByEmail is better.